# Best way to denote time (without date) in Swagger spec

Tags: rest, datetime, jax-rs, json-deserialization, swagger-2.0

What is the best way to represent a time field in a swagger specification, the closest type to denote it looks like `date-time` but this makes standard deserialisers to expect date field to be passed along with the time... Is there a standard or best practice to just denote time in a swagger spec that works well with the Jackson deserialisers?

Is denoting time in milliseconds/seconds and using type `string` in swagger an acceptable approach?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're trying to represent, this may or may not be a good idea.

If you want to represent a specific timestamp, then it's probably much safer to include the date.

If the date really isn't important (eg. you want to indicate that an event takes place at 14:00 every day), then I don't believe swagger has a built in format for that. However, [the swagger format field is open](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#format)  and swagger has support for [ECMA 262 regex string patterns](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern).